# WPF Use same panel in different windows

Tags: wpf

In my WPF application I have a panel, with labels and textboxes, which are being filled with database data. I use that panel in different windows. To make my code more maintainable, I wonder if there's a possibility to put that panel in a seperate file and refer to it. (Such like an include in HTML). When I have to make changes I only have to change one file. I have searched for it, but I couldn't find it, maybe I've searched on the wrong words.

Greets,

Sven

Answer (score 0):

You need [UserControl](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/user-control-in-wpf/). It provides a simple way to create a control. Put some functionality in it and use one `UserControl` in different windows.
Read this [Wpf UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

OK, the WPF concept you are after is called a 'strongly typed datatemplate'

Try this tutorial https://www.codemag.com/Article/0907111/Dressing-Up-Your-Data-with-WPF-DataTemplates

This is an advanced topic, so you need to take the time to understand how they work, and how to create them.